# Is there any mistake in this code, which shows fast scroll list with alphabet preview

Tags: android, listview

I am facing problem in showing the preview of first letter in Android listview, when i do fast scroll i get the preview of text but it will be pointing to the wrong location in list.

For eg, please have a look at the below image, in this now we are in M section, still L letter is appearing.

[image]

Here is the Listadapter code, which implements the above Technic, any mistake in the code?

```
    class MyListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        SectionIndexer 
{

    HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    String[] sections;

    public MyListAdaptor(Context context, LinkedList<String> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, items);

        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int size = items.size();

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            String s = items.get(x);

            // get the first letter of the store
            String ch = s.substring(0, 1);
            // convert to uppercase otherwise lowercase a -z will be sorted
            // after upper A-Z
            ch = ch.toUpperCase();

            // HashMap will prevent duplicates
            alphaIndexer.put(ch, x);
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();

        // create a list from the set to sort
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(
                sectionLetters);

        Collections.sort(sectionList);

        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];

        sectionList.toArray(sections);
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you is the item before Macua a word with a begining letter of L?

Comment: Yes, there is a item ends with L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `alphaIndexer.put(ch, x);` to prevent duplicates, you are keeping the last position for an element starting with `ch` instead of the first one. That is because each call to `put` other than the first with a given key will update the old value. Try with this code and you will be one step closer:

```
if( !alphaIndexer.containsKey(ch) )
    alphaIndexer.put(ch, x);
```

Comment: May i know the reason why, the appropriate letter is not getting displayed?, the code what i have posted is the correct way of implementing right?

Comment: @LLL: Not really, you are working with characters as 1-lengthed strings, relaying on hashmap for uniqueness, and you certainly do things in a far fetched way... The correct section is being displayed (L) so you certainly messed up its position. Have you actually tried my suggestion?