# Alphabetical FastScroll

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll

I am trying to create a fast Scroll with Alphabetical letters. Can somebody tell me how can I use [the code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658591/is-there-any-mistake-in-this-code-which-shows-fast-scroll-list-with-alphabet-pr/) in another class? I have a class with a method that returns letters I need to put in the fast scroll, so I want to use this class in another one, like this:

```
MyListAdaptor mla = new MyListAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), itemsBP);
mla.xyz();
```

but then I don't know how I can make the letters appear.

If you can, help me please.

Comment: I'm giving him a parameter list that I want (itemsBP), there's something missing for the operation? I have no adpter ... actually my difficulty is understanding the steps needed to create this FastScroll.

if you can, please helpe me.

Thank you,

Soraia Oliveira

Comment: So you copy his adapter to test FastScroll?

Comment: i think yes... can you tell me what I need to do to put this code to work on my? i really appreciate your help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of some research I realized that what was missing was the following code, which must be placed in OnCreate ():

```
LinkedList <String> mLinked <String> = new LinkedList ();
for (int i = 0; i <nomes.length: i + +) {
mLinked.add (names [i]);
}

setListAdapter (new MyListAdaptor (this, mLinked));

ListView lv = getListView ();
lv.setFastScrollEnabled (true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener () {
public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
/ / When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text


Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), ((TextView) view). GetText (). ToString (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.) Show ();
}
});
```

And put the class code within the class [MyListAdaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658591/is-there-any-mistake-in-this-code-which-shows-fast-scroll-list-with-alphabet-pr/) Main OnCreate ().

Thanks for the help and hopefully this can help others in the future.